# Python bisection search not running and no error message. MIT edX

Tags: python, edx

The problem is from the MIT edX Python Course 6.00.1 Problem Set 1 Part C. [Here are the problems. Scroll to part C](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-0001-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-in-python-fall-2016/assignments/MIT6_0001F16_ps1.pdf). I'm aware that there are countless questions asked about the edX course but none of them have really helped me. Whenever I run my bisection search code, nothing happens. No error message, nothing. Could someone help me find the issue in my code? Sorry if code is horribly inefficient, very new to python and programming.

```
#Python script for finding optimal saving rate of monthly salary in order to purchase 1M house in 36 months


salary = float(input("Enter salary: "))
total_cost = 1000000
salary_raise = 0.07 #semiannual raise rate
down = 0.25 * total_cost #downpayment
steps = 0 
r = 0.04 #annual investments returns
low = 0 #low parameter for bisection search
high = 10000 #high parameter
current_savings = 0 


while (current_savings <= (down - 100)) or (current_savings >= (down + 100)):
        current_savings = 0 
        monthly_salary = salary/12
        guess_raw = (high + low)/2 
        guess = guess_raw/10000.0
        months = 0
        steps += 1

        while months < 36:  #Finds end amount of money after 36 months based on guess 
            months += 1
            multiple = months%6 
            monthly_savings = monthly_salary * guess
            current_savings = current_savings + monthly_savings + current_savings*r/12
            if multiple == 0:
                monthly_salary += salary_raise * monthly_salary   

        if (current_savings >= (down - 100)) and (current_savings <= (down + 100)):  #If the guess is close enough, print the rate and number of steps taken
            print ("Best savings rate: ",guess)
            print ("Steps in bisection search: ",steps)
            break

        elif current_savings < (down - 100):  #If the guess is low, set the low bound to the guess
            if guess == 9999: 
                print ("It is not possible to pay the down payment in three years.")
                break
            else:
                low = guess 

        elif current_savings > (down + 100): #If the guess is high, set the high bound to the guess
            high = guess
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Don't expect anyone to go off-site to answer your question.

Comment: When you say "nothing happens", do you mean it just exits without printing anything, or that it goes into what seems like an infinite loop? And what input are you giving it?

Comment: At any rate, if you don't know how to use a debugger (although this is a great time to learn…), the way to figure out what's happening is to add a bunch of `print` statements at different points, so you can see if the values are changing the way you expected them to. This will be much easier for you than for anyone else, because you know what you expected each part of the code to do, since you wrote it, but anyone else would have to figure out the intention.

Comment: If you do that and still can't figure out what's wrong, you'll at least have a more specific question, like "why did `guess` go up from 23 to 42 in the third loop when I thought that because <describe your logic> it could only go down from there?"

Comment: Thanks for the help, I found the issue in my code.